# MS Excel: Add a sheet's name into a cell without using a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook with several sheets and I want to have a separate sheet to show items from the previous sheets. So, I have sheets labelled "Tables", "Chairs", "Shelves" and "Results". Each of the furniture sheets keeps a record of how many broken items there are and the "Result" sheet shows all of the information at a glance.

Each furniture sheet has a column "Status" which indicates whether a piece of furniture is broken or good and I use COUNTIF() to sum the results, e.g.:

```
Furniture | Number of broken
-----------------------------
Chairs    | =COUNTIF(Chairs!G:G, "Broken")
```

This gives me the count of broken items from the "Chairs" sheet. However, if I rename the "Chairs" sheet to something else, I also have to rename the "Chairs" cell under "Furniture". COUNTIF() automatically renames the referenced sheet and I'm looking for similar functionality to display just the sheet's name in a cell.

I found this function:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

but it only displays the name of the current spreadsheet. Is there a way to modify it to refer to another sheet without using a VBA script?

Answer (score 2):

Under Furniture you can create a list of Sheet Names:
Create a Define Name name it SheetNames
In refers to write:  `=GET.WORKBOOK(1)&T(NOW())`
In A2 foe example in Result sheet under Furniture write the following:
`=INDEX(MID(SheetNames,FIND("]",SheetNames)+1,255),ROWS(A$1:A1))`

and drag it down to have all the sheets, whenever you change the name of a sheet it will reflect in the column
If you get #REF! it means no more sheets
Now you have to use Indirect in countif to reflect the sheet name:

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(A2&"!G:G"),"Broken")`
and you can drag it
`INDIRECT(A2&"!G:G")` is the equivalent of `Chairs!G:G")`

Answer (score 0):

Yass,

Your formula will work fine, with modification:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",chairs!A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",chairs!A1))+1,255)
```

The CELL function returns information on the cell specified in the second parameter. So by changing it from A1 to chairs!A1, the information comes from the chairs worksheet, not the default, which is the worksheet where the formula is entered.